# Quotient of 2 holomorphic functions which may be holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f and g be two holomorphic functions on a domain $\Omega$. Suppose that $\frac{f}{g}$ is always finite (while g can be zero at some points). Is it true that then $\frac{f}{g}$ is holomorphic? Actually I do not know any example of 2 such functions, except of course the trivial case $f=cg$ where c is a constant. It will be thus very helpful if someone can provide nontrivial examples. Thanks in advance!

Edit: finally, this is standard thing about removable singularities. Nothing more needed! Thanks!

Comment: An easy example: $f(z)=z^{n+1}$, $g(z)=z^n$

Comment: You might like to look at [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity).

Comment: @Adolfo Thanks for your comment! About that easy example, well I'm looking for examples different from that kind. To produce examples of that kind, we take h holomorphic and we write h= (hf)/f :). I want to see more nontrival examples, where f and g don't have easily seen common factors.

Comment: How about $g=e^z$? There are entire functions.

Comment: @Jez Thanks. I see your point, so it seems that the answer is affirmative.

Comment: @AlexYoucis ok, but $e^z$ doesn't vanish at any point, so it is not interesting.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg well, I see I omitted many quite standard things. But the first part of my question asks for the general statement. It turns out to be a simple observation on removable singularities.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg your comment about my ill formulation is right, but I did not know the answer. Being a physics major, I just returned to complex analysis, and suddenly I saw a so naive question but I ignored from the first time I learned complex analysis (or I just didn't remember all the details of this subject). Then I think a question like this may be benefit to someone else, maybe other beginners. So I asked it, to save my time, and maybe to help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: yes. I am going to formalize where you said "$f/g$ is always finite" to mean: "for any $P \in \Omega$, if $g$ has a zero at $P$, then $f$ has a zero of at least the same order."

Recall that we define the order of a zero to be smallest $n \geq 0$ such that $f^{(n)}(P) \neq 0$ but $f^{(n-1)}(P) = 0$. That this exists (when the function is not identically the zero function) is a consequence of holomorphicity, which is obvious if you already know that holomorphic functions are analytic.

Given that $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic, this is the only hypothesis needed to ensure that $f/g$ admits a holomorphic continuation to a domain including $P$. Moreover, this condition is necessary. This is seen easily by Taylor expanding at $P$.

In particular, if a continuous extension exists, it is automatically holomorphic.

Comment: thanks, I get it. Being a physics major, sometimes I forget to formalize things properly. Another naive question, what about real functions (smooth but not analytic for example)? From your answer, it seems to me that holomorphicity=analyticity is a key ingredient.

Comment: i don't know how to formalize the question for such a function, e.g. consider a bump function; what is its order of vanishing at the origin?